# .htaccess file - removing .php extension "Server Error"

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I have just created a `.htaccess` file which I'm using in XAMPP, and is located in `Z:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess` and I've added the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ (.*)$1.php [L,QSA]
```

But when I load any of my pages I get the error:

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
```

I've seen others come across this error before and have tried other people's fixes but nothing has worked for me, when I stop getting the error, it doesnt remove the .php extension.

**Does anyone know what the issue is?**

Comment: What does the error log say? You should be able to access it through XAMPP's control panel.

Comment: are you sure mode rewrite is on?

Comment: This line     **RewriteRule ^(.*)$1.php [L,QSA]** has the problem , there should be a space between RewritePattern and the rewrite path, **(.*) $1.php** ( **(.*)space$1.php** )

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes rewrite is on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

as well as in Apache `httpd.conf` check rewrite is on

Comment: This worked, I just hadn't removed the extension from the links so it was still showing up. Thanks!

Comment: @drewith happy to help :)